# Issues with Subcaption package and spacing

Tags: floats, subcaption, vspace

I lately added the `subcaption` package to my article in order to place my figures and caption them accordingly. Before I embedded the figures like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
%\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
        \hrule
        \vspace*{2mm}
        \centering
        \rule{5cm}{5cm}
        \rule{5cm}{5cm}
        \vspace*{2mm}
        \hrule
        \caption{Some Caption}
        \vspace*{2mm}
        \hrule
        \label{fig:somefigure}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

with looked like this:

[image: Nice spacing around caption]

Since I wanted subcaptions, `subcaption` seemed to be the recommended choice. However, now my figures  (code yet unchanged to actually include subcaptions) look like this:

[image: Not-so-nice spacing around caption]

The `subcaption` package causes this weird vertical spacing around the caption between the two `\hrule`s. I tried understanding the `caption` manual, as suggested, but I can't figure out why this happens and how to make it stop. Eliminating the `\vspace*{2mm}` after the caption still leaves a big gap.

Comment: Please make your MWE self contained. Currently you are using code and images we do not have accesss to. Make an example that others can copy as is and see if they get the same results. As images you can use say `\rule{5cm}{5cm}`

Comment: @daleif, I added an MWE including my full preamble.

Comment: The 'M' stands for minimal, so your full preamble is definitely too much. As far as I can see the only package relevant to the issue is `subcaption`.

Comment: when `subcaption` is loaded the `caption` package is also loaded, which sets the space above a caption to something else than the default. As campa says, your example is far from minimal, the only relevant thing for this is the subcaption package.

Comment: I would suggest reading the caption manual. You might even be able to build those lines directly into the caption command so you don't have to do this manually. See section 4 of the caption manual

Comment: I understand that the 'M' stands for minimal. However, my assumption was that the issue is somehow related to ```subcaption``` _and_ another package, or the order of my preamble, hence the full preamble. It didn't come to my mind to try the MWE with only the one package. I'm going to reformulate the question.

Comment: Try adding `\captionsetup{figureposition=b}` after loading the `subcaption` package.

Comment: @P.M. here we go! That works, thanks! The space around is slightly bigger than without the ```subcaption```package though, but I guess I can live with that.

Comment: Note that captions (any captions) typically use \abovecaptionskip and \belowcaptionskip to add spacing,  These values vary and swap places, but one of them is usually 0pt.  Use \the\abovecaptionskip etc. to find their current values.